# How can can I repair peeling shower drain coating?

Tags: shower, drain, sealant

There is some kind of plastic coating over my drain that is peeling and needs replacing. I can't work out what kind of product I would need to use to recover it to protect the plug and would appreciate any advice!

[image: image attached of peeling plug hole]

Comment: I'd be replacing the assembly with a shiny new chrome one. They're not expensive, and assuming you have access they're not usually complicated.

Answer (score 5):

This white coating isn't actually *sealant*. The seal to keep water from leaking is either some plumber's putty under the rim of the drain or a foam or rubber gasket (and yours is *probably* plumber's putty). So long as the drain isn't actually leaking water, there is no *technical* reason for that white layer to be there. It appears to be purely aesthetic.

Generally, in the US at least, that part of the drain is either plastic or metal and chromed, though some are white plastic. It appears to me that yours is actually metal and that someone in the past may have painted it white to hide the scratching and pitting in the part.

Should you not like the look of the pitted metal underneath (and it does look rough), you could either replace the drain<sup>*</sup>, or you could remove it then recoat it with either paint (which may not last a terribly long time), white epoxy (which should last a very long time) or possibly a white rubberized coating like PlastiDip™ (which should also last a long time).

Any recoating would require proper preparation which would include making sure that the part is dry, scraping off the old coat, giving it a good sanding to ensure any rust and corrosion are removed and that the surface is smooth. Then, follow any extra instructions for the product you choose.

---

<sup>*</sup>Replacement is *very much* within the realm of DIY, and replacement parts should be rather inexpensive - probably less than what I've seen some people spend at McDonald's for lunch...

Comment: Replacement of the drain can be outside the skill level of some DIYers. Especially since the possibility of leaks, if the job isn't done well, can cause some serious and expensive issues.  Not advised for someone new to doing their home repairs. After having some problem solving experiences, then sure maybe a try.

Comment: Fair point, @RMDman. A few _good_ YouTube* videos should be sufficient to learn the skills. Of course, asking here (after searching first, of course) should also help. *NOTE: YT is _notorious_ for _bad_ teaching, so watching several and trusting gut instinct as to "this gal's got it right" and "that guy's an idiot", as well as several confirming the "this is right" instinct is always recommended.

Comment: I've gotten the "this person's got it right" and "this person's an idiot" vibe from actual "professionals" I've paid to do the work for me as well.  Sometimes YouTube imitates life...

Answer (score 1):

That is starting to corrode. The factory applied paint is peeling off. You could sand it and tape off around it and apply an epoxy primer and paint. However if it is corroded on top it may be corroded underneath and can start leaking, giving you more problems. Most of the time these things are replaced. Especially if the tub gets everyday use. If you are up for trying a replacement, ask the question of how. If not, it may be time to call a plumber.

Comment: That ain't factory-applied :D